# SQLAlchemy: how to pass extra parameters when instantiating new object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have defined a table, using SQLAlchemy and mapped it to a class:

```
meta = MetaData(engine)
item_table = Table(
    'Item', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('name', String(40), nullable=False)
)

class Item(object):
    def init(self, created_by):
        self.created_by = created_by
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Item %r created by %r>' % (self.name, self.created_by)

mapper(Item, item_table)
```

As you see, the `Item` has a `created_by` field that does not come from the database. Currently I survive using `item.init("created_by")` method, what is called immediately after creating an instance of item. I find this kind of ugly, perhaps there is a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [`load`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load) event and execute your logic there:

```
class DB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._register_event()

    def _get_created_by(self):
        return datetime.datetime.now()

    def _register_event(self):
        @event.listens_for(Item, 'load')
        def receive_load(target, context):
            target.created_by = self._get_created_by()

    def test_select(self):
        items = session.query(Item).all()
        for item in items:
            print(item)

db = DB()
db.test_select()
```

Comment: I create my items by `item = session.query(Item).get(item_id)`, I don't see where I can pass the extra parameter there.

Comment: OK. This is not *creation* of new objects. This is *retrieval* of persistent objects from the database. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: where does `created_by` come from, if it's not stored in the database?

Comment: @Eevee, the actual context is pretty complicated to explain it here, that would be kind of off-topic. Let's say it's a temporary run-time metadata, that need not to persist in the database.

Comment: @van in what scope this event function will be executed? I am interested in a reference to the object in which's scope the retrieval took place. Ie, smuggle the `self` somehow in the newly created instance.

Comment: `target` is actually *`self`*

Comment: No no, I meant the `self` of the context where the retrieval is initiated (a method in a certain class that manages the retrieval actions), not the object that is populated with the retrieved data.

Comment: Well, define this event listener inside the scope of that `class`.

Comment: Bingo, closure, that nails it. For some stupid reason, I did not even consider using the event decorator inside the class function code block.

Comment: it took some iterations :)